# Update to database with Codeigniter won't work

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, for-loop, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm facing a problem with my update to the database. I've try to make an sort system with pictures but it won't work. I'm using the sortable function of Jquery. With that I get my array back from the current sort (on save).

Everything works fine if I move an image from place 1 to place 2. So the oldSortNumber is 1 and the new one is 2 (1 + 1). Here is my code:

```
public function updateOrder ($newSortArray) {
    for($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++)
    {
        $oldSortNumber = substr($newSortArray['img'][$i], strpos($newSortArray['img'][$i], ".") + 1);
        $newSortNumber = $i + 1;

        $this->db->where('sortID', $oldSortNumber);
        $this->db->update('user_image', array('sortID' => $newSortNumber));
    }
}
```

When I'm placing the images back (so from 2 to 1, or something like that) my function won't work. So it won't update to my new position. 1 instead of 2.

So in my database I've an picture with sortOrder 2. If I'm placing it on the third place. Everything works fine. But when I'm positioning it to the first place, it won't update to the database. The input is fine and I don't know what's wrong. Can somebody help me?

Comment: where you are defining `$oldSortNumber`. I think it should b `$i`

Comment: And your loop is not correct it should be  `for($i = 5; $i > 0; $i--)` because your update is beginning from 1 and making it 2 when your $i is 2 you have two row with 2

Comment: Uh I updated my code. I get my old number out of the "serializable"function from the Jquery UI. So that one puts my 6 positions in an row. So I check from 1 to 6 which are the new numbers.

Answer (score 1):

its not going to work like this because of your where and your update data is in same column. you have to use ID of the `user_image` table , the primary key in where condition and set the query value old sort order to table id

```
public function updateOrder ($newSortArray) {
for($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++)
{
    $ID = substr($newSortArray['img'][$i], strpos($newSortArray['img'][$i], ".") + 1);

    $this->db->where('YOUR_TABLE_ID', $ID );
    $this->db->update('user_image', array('sortID' => $i ));
}
}
```

Comment: Ah allright, so the failure is in the where clause. I will try to get the image ID in the where clause. The problem is that the serializable function from the Jquery UI sortable is that it returns the old and new sort orders. So I've first to get the image ID by the old sort order. And then use that imageID to set the new Order. I will try that this evening. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: The only thing which is strange, is that if I place the image higher in sortOrder, it works fine. And when I put this lower, it fails.

Comment: Because when its higher its start from the bottom means 5 will be 5+1 so highest value is changing to something new. but when its lower ie 1 is becoming 1+1 = 2 but you already have another 2, so when your $i is 2 your condition is where 2 is selecting two row, the updated one and the old one. Logically its wrong, your where condition value should not be change.

Comment: Ah yess! I understand that. So it's selecting two rows instead of 1. I think I've to change the $newSortArray that it has to give the imageID instead of the old sort id. And then set the sortID to the new id. Yes thanks!